# How can I play a mp3 url on Apple Watch?

Tags: swift, apple-watch

```
func initPlay() {
    let asset = AVURLAsset(url: url!, options: nil)
    let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
    g_CurrentPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)
    g_CurrentPlayer.play()
}
```

Comment: It works on simulator.  But I can't hear it on real device - iWatch.  there is any setting for real device?

Comment: thanks for your formatting. I am trying to hear with airpods. but it doesn't hear.